# jQuery Validation - Comparing values from the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have x number of textboxes with same class name. I want the user to enter dates in them and each date should be greater than the previous one. How can I achieve this?

jQuery -

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterrule", function(value, element, param) {
   return $(param).not(element).get().every(function(item) {
     return $(item).val() < value;
 });
}, "Please specify a greater value");


jQuery.validator.addClassRules("dept_date", {
  greaterrule: ".dept_date"
});
```

HTML -

```
First Date <input type="text" name="first_date" class="dept_date"> <br>
Second Date <input type="text" name="second_date" class="dept_date"> <br>
Third Date <input type="text" name="third_date" class="dept_date"> <br>
Fourth Date <input type="text" name="fourth_date" class="dept_date"> <br>
```

Comment: On textchange event or whatever it is, write logic to compare it from previous textbox entry.

Comment: use `.prev(".dept_date")` to get the previous element with dept_date class

Comment: are the textboxes cloned ?

Comment: @mmr - Look at the html part which I just added. That how the textboxs are.

Comment: In your case, `.addClassRules()` is totally unnecessary because `class="greaterrule"` is functionally equivalent.  And the `param` argument makes absolutely no sense since there is no parameter being set where this rule is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `prevAll` to check against all the dates before and use `Date` to compare:-

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterrule", function(value, element, param) {

  return $(element).prevAll(param).get().every(function(prev) {
      return new Date($(prev).val()) < new Date($(element).val());
  });

}, "Please specify a greater value");


jQuery.validator.addClassRules("dept_date", {
  greaterrule: ".dept_date"
});

$("form").validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
  First Date
  <input type="text" value="01/21/2016" name="first_date" class="dept_date">
  <br>Second Date
  <input type="text" value="01/22/2016" name="second_date" class="dept_date">
  <br>Third Date
  <input type="text" value="01/23/2016" name="third_date" class="dept_date">
  <br>Fourth Date
  <input type="text" value="01/24/2016" name="fourth_date" class="dept_date">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The `param` argument makes absolutely no sense since there is no parameter being set where this rule is declared.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more please @Sparky, as `param` comes through as `.dept_date` which is being passed in from `addClassRules`.

Comment: What doesn't work? the snippet works as you required.

Comment: Your code is working on a test page, however when I implement the same work on my main project it doesn't give me any output. I am finding my mistakes, I will let you know.

Comment: BG101, your code worked well, however when I add a table in HTML codes it stopped working. Here is the jsfiddle for both [Without table](https://jsfiddle.net/paoqa8z2/) and [With table](https://jsfiddle.net/3mmusaqx/)

Comment: That is because `prevAll` works by looking in its direct, previous siblings and not in nested elements. you can change it to use `index` like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/BG101/3mmusaqx/1/). and upvote / marked as correct would be appreciated.